# WCF Service strange behavior: Entity Framework throws an exception when running the code, but works fine when debugging

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, debugging

I have a WCF service, that is using Entity Framework to connect to a database. I came across some kind of a strange behavior - when I start debugging the WCF service and invoke one of its methods (Operation Contracts), I get two different scenarios depending on the way I debug. Meaning, when I just invoke the method, without stepping into the code, I get an exception, stating: "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_TagIsUsedInPublication'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.TagIsUsedInPublication'. The duplicate key value is (16, 54)." On the other hand, when I put a breakpoint at the beginning of the method and step into the code and go through it line by line, everything works fine. How is this possible and what am I doing wrong?

My method uses two of the entities from the database - Publication and Tag. I also have a bridge table, called TagIsUsedInPublication. It has two foreign keys - one pointing to the Publication table, and another - to the Tag one. It has a compound primary key, consisting of the two columns (the foreign key ones). Of course, this means Publication and Tag have many-to-many relationship.

Here is my method:

```
public static bool EditPublication(Interpretum.InterpretumService.SimplePublication publication)
{
    try
    {
        InterpretumDAL.InterpretumEntities interpretumEntities = new InterpretumDAL.InterpretumEntities();

        InterpretumDAL.Publication publicationDbContext =
            (from p in interpretumEntities.Publications
             where p.Id == publication.Id
             select p).SingleOrDefault();

        // This method just gets all the properties of my custom SimplePublication class and maps them to the Publication entity.
        publicationDbContext = publication.ToDbContext(publicationDbContext);

        if (publication.Tags.Count != 0)
        {
            publicationDbContext.Tags = Tag.RenderTagList(publication.Tags, publication.CreationUserId, interpretumEntities);
        }

        interpretumEntities.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // I added this throw line just to see what actually is causing the method fail. 
        throw e;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The RenderTagList method is necessary because my schema requires uniqe values for the Name column of the Tag table. So, it is checking whether there's already a tag with the name provided. If there is, it is added to the list of Tags. If it isn't, a new one is created and only then it is added to the list.

Here's what this method looks like:

```
public static List<InterpretumDAL.Tag> RenderTagList(List<SimpleTag> simpleTags, int creationUserId, InterpretumDAL.InterpretumEntities interpretumEntities)
{
    List<InterpretumDAL.Tag> tags = new List<InterpretumDAL.Tag>();

    foreach (var simpleTag in simpleTags)
    {
        InterpretumDAL.Tag tag = interpretumEntities.Tags.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == simpleTag.Name);

        if (tag == null)
        {
            tag = new InterpretumDAL.Tag()
            {
                Name = simpleTag.Name,
                CreationUserId = creationUserId
            };
        }

        tags.Add(tag);
    }

    return tags;
}
```

As I wrote above, when I just invoke the EditPublication, an exception is thrown. Of course, I invoke it with the same values every time and no matter how many times I invoke it, I always get this exception. However, when I step into the code and step over the method line by line, everything works fine.

I have to mention that I am fairly new to Entity Framework, so it is quite possible that I am doing something wrong. The problem is that I can't see what I am doing wrong, just because of this unpredictable behavior.

**Edit 1:**

Stack trace:

```
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
```

Comment: Please post stack trace.

Comment: I think that you may be using a different data source depending on the mode you're running in. Something perhaps like #if(DEBUG) use datasource A #else use data source B.

Comment: Another, perhaps more probable explanation is that you have race conditions in your code? That might explain why step by step works fine.

Comment: I fixed the bug and I don't get the exception no more, but I still can't realize why I got the different results depending on the way I run the code. No, I don't have conditional compilation, like the one in your example. And by the way, what is a race condition?